# Is there a one-word translation for the English adjective 'unintelligent'?

Tags: word-meaning, translation, adjectives, single-words

I believe that 'intelligente' is a good translation for the English word 'intelligent'. Is there a suitable one-word translation for the English 'unintelligent'? My dictionary suggests 'poco intelligente' but it offers no single word translation.

Answer (score 6):

As reported in [this dictionary](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Inglese/U/unintelligent.shtml), you can use the term ***ottuso***.

> **unintelligent** agg. non intelligente, ***ottuso***, stupido.

Looking at Treccani’s dictionary you can read the definition of [ottuso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ottuso/), used figuratively:

> 3. In senso fig., sempre in contrapp. con acuto: a. Con riferimento alla capacità intellettiva, che manca di penetrazione, tardo a capire,
>      di scarsa sensibilità: *mente o., cervello o.*; *ma sei proprio o.!*; per
>      estens., *sguardo o., espressione o.*, che rivelano lentezza mentale.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, there is the Italian word **[inintelligente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/inintelligente/)**, which is exactly corresponding to “unintelligent” (the word *intelligente* preceded by the negative prefix *in-*), but it is really uncommon.

As an alternative – but losing the litotes of “unintelligent” – there is a wide range of negative terms for a person or action lacking intelligence: *stupido*, *ottuso*, *scemo* and so on, some of which correspond to similar-sounding English words (stupid, obtuse...).

Personally, to express the nuance of “unintelligent”, I'd tend to use some phrase negating *intelligente* or another positive term: *un ragazzo non molto sveglio* for “a quite unintelligent boy”, say.